# How to start and stop recording/capturing as a video file from web cam using opencv?

Tags: c++, opencv, video

I have a project, where I want to save the streaming video from webcam, frame by frame to a avi file using opencv with C++. I know how to do that.

My problem is to save the streaming video to a file, only if there is a change in the frame.

I want to compare the current frame with previous frame (from the streaming video from webcam) and save the frame to .avi file if there is any change.

Basically I need help with a function in opencv which can provide a way to start and stop recording a video to a file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
int main( ) {
CvCapture* capture;

Mat A,B,C;

capture = cvCreateCameraCapture(0);

assert( capture != NULL );

IplImage* bgr_frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );

CvSize size = cvSize(
                 (int)cvGetCaptureProperty( capture,
                                           CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH),
                 (int)cvGetCaptureProperty( capture,
                                           CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)
                 );

cvNamedWindow( "Webcam", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );

CvVideoWriter *writer =         cvCreateVideoWriter("I:/vidtry.AVI",CV_FOURCC('D','I','V','X'),15,size);
int x=1;

do
{
if(x==1)
{
    A=Mat(bgr_frame);
    x=0;
}

B=Mat(bgr_frame);
compare(A,B,C,CMP_EQ);
int flag=0;

for(int y = 0; y < C.rows; y++)
{
for(int x = 0; x < C.cols; x++)
{
    if(C.at<unsigned char>(y, x)==255)
        continue;
    else
        flag=1;
}
}
if(flag==0)
cvWriteFrame(writer, bgr_frame );

cvShowImage( "Webcam", bgr_frame );
char c = cvWaitKey( 33 );
if( c == 27 ) break;
A=bgr_frame;
}
while( (bgr_frame = cvQueryFrame( capture )) != NULL ) ;

cvReleaseVideoWriter( &writer );
cvReleaseCapture( &capture );
cvDestroyWindow( "Webcam" );
return( 0 );
}
```

Comment: Please show us what have you tried so far.

Comment: No one can answer that???